# R GRMetric: How to personalize the plot design (themes, colors, legends, etc.)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to R and interested in Plotting Dose-Response curves. I have discovered GRMetrics which I found is very useful.

Example (as given in the documentary) will produce a scatter blot and plots the approximated function above them - perfect but how to persolanize the plot design with respect to the color of the points and curves, axis labels, thickness, etc. 
In the documentaiton I found it is compatible with ggplot2 but I didn't found any example and didn't manage to integrate the output of GRMetric in a ggplot environment to edit the graph.

I appreciate any suggestion how to solve this issue.

The installation and code for GRMetrics:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly=TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GRmetrics")
install.packages("foreign")

browseVignettes("GRmetrics")   #link to documentation

library(GRmetrics)
data(inputCaseA)
head(inputCaseA)

drc_output = GRfit(inputCaseA, groupingVariables =c('cell_line','agent'))
GRdrawDRC(drc_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested: one solution I found for this problem is....
1) export the curve parameters and data points from GRdrawDRC. The GRmetrics packages uses sigmoidal fitting and the function is given in its documentation 
2) copy/insert the curve and all parameters in ggplot (e.g. as stat_function + geom_point()).

Then you are off to go and can format the graph easily.